# Gui library with support for user movable widgets

Tags: linux, library, c++, gui, c

After *hard* work, I have managed to write a working "widget canvas" for GTK-3.0. The user is able to move native `GtkWidget`s by dragging them around, pretty much like MDI.

However, moving a widget is slow. As soon as the number of widget increases, I get frametimes whell above 20 ms. After benchmarking, I have found that `gtk_container_propagate_draw` is a huge bottleneck:

```
ui/widget_canvas_internal.cpp:operator():73 29046505 ns

ui/line_segment_renderer.cpp:draw_callback:56  33100 ns
```

`operator()` basically calls `gtk_container_propagate_draw` on each child widget. The widgets mainly contains `GtkLabel`s and `GtkSlider`s.

For reference, here is a link to the project:

https://github.com/milasudril/texpainter

The widget canvas is found here

- https://github.com/milasudril/texpainter/blob/master/ui/widget_canvas.hpp
- https://github.com/milasudril/texpainter/blob/master/ui/widget_canvas.cpp
- https://github.com/milasudril/texpainter/blob/master/ui/widget_canvas_internal.hpp
- https://github.com/milasudril/texpainter/blob/master/ui/widget_canvas_internal.cpp

The purpose of the widget canvas is to implement a "Node editor", similar to what you find in Blender. Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

The connections are drawn on top of the other widgets. The widget canvas is much like a GtkLayout, with support for multiple "layers".

**Question:**

Should I try to replace GTK-3.0 with something else, and if so, what? I think it is a good idea to know how good the library is at handling user movable widgets, so porting the UI part would be worth the effort. Target platform is currently GNU/Linux desktop.

Comment: I tend to recommend Qt, although I have not yet myself tested something similar to what you want to do on Linux. But if something is capable of that, it's Qt.

Comment: @Sebastian Using QMdiArea? I see from the docs that QLayout does not have a "draw" callback like GtkContainer, so maybe that could be more efficient. May have a look at Qt later, though its integration with GTK-based desktop environments is not perfect.

Comment: @Sebastian. Hmm Qt appears to allow "layoutless" placement. Maybe I should give it a shot. That is coming to GTK-4.0.

Comment: I can't tell you which Qt library to use in particular, but I know 100% it can do what you want. And I don't see any issues with running it in a GTK environment. You are probably using a bunch of Qt-based apps already without knowing it.